# Sherlock’s hidden message #3

Tags: encoded-message

For the TV series [*Sherlock*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlock_(TV_series)), BBC published some [fictional websites](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/4yTrVL4srk48mKs8bhK4TvM/other-sherlock-related-websites).

Sherlock’s site, http://thescienceofdeduction.co.uk/, contains three [hidden messages](http://thescienceofdeduction.co.uk/hidden-messages):

> Some anonymous guy has been sending me emails. It could be nothing but I'll post them up here. Could be an interesting case that you can help me with...

It says all three were "Solved", but it seems that the solution for the [hidden message #3](http://thescienceofdeduction.co.uk/hidden-messages/hiddenmessage3) is still missing. Here’s the message:

> Sherlock Holmes!
>
> Here's a picture you might enjoy:
>
> [image: Handwritten coded message]
>
> Also, where is it the pigs live?
>
> Mwah!
>   Xx

What is the solution? How does it work?

Comment: Someone wth the necessary reputation should probably protect this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hidden message is

> SHERLOCK I HAVE FOUND YOU

Form the clue "where is it the pigs live?" I understood it is

> Pigpen cipher

By deciphering, I got

> SHERLOCK I HAVE FOUND YOU

*Source: [Pigpen cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigpen_cipher) (You will get the idea about how to replace the code with corresponding alphabets from there)*

Answer (score 2):

The hidden message is:

> SHERLOCK I HAVE FOUND YOU

I didn't use the clue "where is it the pigs live?", but instead I used:

> http://observeanalysededuce.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/pigpen.png
>  If you click into the link above, you will see four different grids. And according to the grids, we can find that different symbols (just like in the message) mean different letters. So, if we follow the grids, we can find the hidden message.

Comment: Doesn't the clue lead to what the cipher is? You even have it as the name of the png in your URL!

Comment: Yes, the url say what the cipher is but I more focus on the hidden message

Comment: If you didn't use the info that the cipher is 'pigpen' then how did you find that link containing image of pigpen cipher symbols?

Comment: I like solving coded message with grid and I don't know how I found out the link of this image is somehow match the question

Answer (score -2):

The answer is "Sherlock I have found you". The key to finding the answer is masonic cipher (also pigpen cipher).

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! This question has already been answered.

Answer (score -4):

It's pretty easy to figure out I have worked out what it says: "Sherlock I have found you" it's an easy message code. You use a grid that shows the symbols in patterns.